# Where can I find information about PCI devices in Linux?

Tags: pci

I'm trying to verify a program's output with my machine. This is the program's output

```
 pci_type_0=BlockDevice,
 pci_type_1=NetworkDevice,
 pci_type_2=NetworkDevice,
 pci_type_3=BlockDevice
```

My job is to verify that these information is correct. I've tried looking through with lspci but I'm not sure if that's the correct information I need.

Is there anywhere else besides lspci that I can look?

Comment: You can try scanpci, lshw command

Answer (score 2):

What part of the output of `lspci` is not what you were expecting? I'm pretty sure if `lspci` doesn't have it, you won't find what you need, although you may need to use command line options to get more detailed information.

`lspci` gets its information from `/sys`; specifically, `/sys/bus/pci/devices`. You could try looking at that. Beware, that information isn't meant for human consumption, and might be difficult to understand without the documentation.